# Can't get correct values of a list of objects of my own class

Tags: java, android, list, class, object

I have a class that storage some information. I have also an array of objects of this class "Points[]", all the information is added correctly, but when I want to have information of some of this "Points", for example:

```
point[1].getId();
```

I have the last Id value, but I want the 1 value. Even if the "[i]" value is 1 or 2 or any number I only recieve de last Id value that I added before. I put the class code and the main code for explain it better.

Point class:

```
public class Point implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4910520794768384111L;

    String _id;
    String _comment;
    String _calification;
    String _coords;
    int _X;
    int _Y;

    public Point(String id, String comment, String calification, String coords, int x, int y)
    {
        _id = id;
        _comment = comment;
        _calification = calification;
        _coords = coords;
        _X = x;
        _Y = y;
    }

    public String getID()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getComment()
    {
        return _comment;
    }

    public String getCalification()
    {
        return _calification;
    }

    public String getCoords()
    {
        return _coords;
    }

    public int getPointX()
    {
        return _X;
    }

    public int getPointY()
    {
        return _Y;
    }
}
```

Main class code, here is where I need to have all the information and I only recieve the last objetc of my Point class information:

```
for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
{                               
    try 
    {
        js.put("id",points[i].getID());
              js.put("calification",points[i].getCalification());
              js.put("comment",points[i].getComment());
              js.put("gps",points[i].getCoords());
              js.put("X",points[i].getPointX());
              js.put("Y",points[i].getPointY());

} 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {                               
         e.printStackTrace();
}
    jsPoints.put(js);
}
```

Also I add one image of the values format in the class.

[image]

Can someone help me with that problem? I need to have the correct value for the "i" number, not only the last one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I belive JS is a hashmap.What is happening is you are putting values in hashmap with particular keys.

```
js.put("id",points[i].getID());
js.put("calification",points[i].getCalification());
js.put("comment",points[i].getComment());
js.put("gps",points[i].getCoords());
js.put("X",points[i].getPointX());
js.put("Y",points[i].getPointY());
```

In the interation what will happen is next iteration will overwrite values saved by previous iteration.And at last you will have only last iteration values in hashmap.

Below is the example

```
js.put("id",1);
js.put("id",2);
js.put("id",3);
js.put("id",4);
```

Here what will happen is you will have only one value in hashmap that is 4.

you should use some other statergy to save those values.

Comment: This is not the problem, I think, becuase I put the "js" then on a JSONArray: "jsPoints.put(js);" and when I see the values on the JSONArray they are always the same, for example, I have 3 points with diferent values and I have three times the same third value on the JSONArray, because the js recieve each time the same last value, even the numbers is 0 or 1 or 2. I add this part of code to help you to understand me.